# vue-simple-calendar - View Date Event after onClick

Tags: javascript, vue.js, plugins, calendar

I am using the "vue-simple-calendar" and I want to get the name and description of an event in my calendar after I clicked on it. The same way it works right here: https://tallent.us/vue-simple-calendar/

This is my calendar:

```html
<calendar-view
    :show-date="showDate"
    :events="events"
    class="theme-default holiday-us-traditional holiday-us-official"
    @click-date="onClickDate"
    @click-event="onClickEvent(calendarItem, windowEvent)"  <-- Issue right here
    :startingDayOfWeek="startingDoW"
>
    <calendar-view-header
        slot="header"
        slot-scope="t"
        :header-props="t.headerProps"
        @input="setShowDate"
     />
</calendar-view>
```

`events` is a custom Array where I can add Items via Input fields

`@click-event` is called when I click on an event in my calendar, but I don't know how to get the name of the event that has been clicked.

In the official docs also isn't a lot of information: https://github.com/richardtallent/vue-simple-calendar#props

How I can address the event that has been clicked?

Comment: @HTLWelsLTLovers: are You following same data-structure for the "event item", as mentioned in https://github.com/richardtallent/vue-simple-calendar#calendar-item-properties?
can You please share the data-structure of the events(custom Array)?

Comment: This [line](https://github.com/richardtallent/vue-simple-calendar-sample/blob/0762779676a0b92a8a218daab0fe6fe28276b528/src/App.vue#L282) in the example displays a function to be fired when `@click-event` is fired. So, maybe you can define a function `onClickItem` as such, change your erronous line to `@click-event="onClickItem"` and try getting `e.title`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to get the title and the dates with `onClickItem`. But somehow I can't adress `e.description`

Thats my data structure so far. 
`events: [{
                    id: '',
                    startDate: new Date(),
                    endDate: new Date(),
                    title: '',
                    description: '',
                }],`
I am currently not generating a unique ID, could this be the case?